# Using default masterpage in Provider Hosted MVC App

Tags: master-page, provider-hosted-app

Is it possible to use the Default SharePoint Masterpage in a Provider Hosted MVC App on the appweb?

I want to have the same branding, quicklaunch bars, side launch bars ect in my provider hosted App and I its not pratical for me to make it into an app part.

How can I implement the default masterpage?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the masterpage in an app using similar code as you would in a regular SharePoint app, but this is not the recommended behavior, use the Chrome Controls instead.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179916.aspx